# Opening scribus using command line

Tags: python, command-line, scribus

I am trying to use the command line scripts of scribus to convert .svg files to .pdf .
When I am trying to use a command like:

scribus -py C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\calc_svg_to_pdf.py

I get an error message that the command scribus is unknown.

When i am executing the script in scribus everything works fine.

I am using scribus 1.5.4 on Windows 10 64 bit with Ghostscript 9.23

Comment: Is the `scribus` folder in your Windows PATH variable?

Comment: no, do you know which folder i must use?

Comment: found it must use the main folder of scribus. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you tell us which folder?

Comment: @Josem it depends whether scribus exec has been compiled, comes from a repo, an appimage or whatever way it can be installed...